# How to show all values on x axis using google graph api for continuous series in iOS

Tags: ios, graph, charts, google-visualization

I need to show every date on x-axis. Using following code. also there is multiple values for single date.

Right now I am getting random date is displaying on x axis. but i need to show every date on x-axis.

```
[NSString *htmlString = \[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>\
                        <head>\
                        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.google.com/jsapi\"></script>\
                        <script type=\"text/javascript\">\
                        google.load(\"visualization\", \"1\", {packages:\[\"corechart\"\], 'language': 'en'});\
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);\
                        function drawChart() {\
                            var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();\
                        dataTable.addColumn('datetime', 'Voltage (V)');\
                        dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Current (mA.)');\
                        \
                        dataTable.addRows(\[\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 1), 10\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 2), 6\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 2), 15\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 2), 10\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 2), 19\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 3), 12\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 4), 22\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 4), 15\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 5), 25\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 6), 26\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 7), 27\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 10), 10\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 10), 19\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 11), 12\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 12), 22\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 13), 15\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 14), 25\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 14), 26\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 15), 27\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 16), 10\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 17), 6\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 18), 15\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 19), 10\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 19), 19\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 19), 12\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 19), 22\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 20), 15\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 20), 25\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 21), 26\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 22), 27\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 23), 10\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 24), 6\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 24), 15\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 24), 10\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 25), 19\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 25), 12\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 25), 22\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 25), 15\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 26), 25\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 27), 26\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 27), 27\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 28), 10\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 28), 6\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 28), 15\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 29), 10\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 29), 19\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 30), 12\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 30), 22\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 30), 15\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 30), 25\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 31), 26\],\
                        \[new Date(2008, 1, 31), 27\]\
                        \]);\
                        \
                        \
                            var options = {\
                        width: 400, height: 240,\
                        legend: { position: 'bottom', alignment:'start'},\
                        interpolateNulls:true,\
                        backgroundColor:'transparent',\
                        legend: {position: 'none'},\
                        titleTextStyle:{color: 'black', fontName: 'verdana', fontSize: 8},\
                        \
                        hAxis:{format: 'dd-MM', textStyle: {color: '#343434',fontName: 'verdana',fontSize:6},slantedText:'true',slantedTextAngle:1, showTextEvery:1, baselineColor:'transparent',gridlineColor: 'transparent', viewWindowMode:'explicit', viewWindow:{ min: new Date(2008,1,1), max: new Date(2008,1,31) } },\
                        vAxis: {textStyle: {color: '#343434',fontName: 'verdana',fontSize:6},baselineColor:'transparent',gridlineColor: 'transparent',viewWindowMode:'explicit', viewWindow:{ min: 0 }},\
                        pointSize:10,\
                        fontSize: 6,\
                        lineWidth:3.0,\
                        tooltip:{textStyle:{color: '#343434', fontName:'verdana',fontSize: 10}, isHtml:'true'},\
                        series: { \
                        0:{color: '#d57829', visibleInLegend: true, lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 4},\
                        1:{color: '#047d94',lineWidth: 0,visibleInLegend: true,pointSize:4},\
                        2:{color: '#d57829', visibleInLegend: true, lineWidth: 0, pointSize: 6},\
                        3:{color: '#047d94',lineWidth: 0,visibleInLegend: true,pointSize:6},\
                        4:{color: '#FFFFFF',visibleInLegend: true, pointSize:0}\
                        }\
                        \
                            };\
                            \
                            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));\
                            chart.draw(dataTable, options);\
                        }\
                        </script>\
                        </head><body style=\"-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);\"> \
                        <div id=\"chart_div\" style=\"width: 2000px; height: 500px;\"></div>\
                        </body>\
                        </html>"\];  

[graphWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil\];
```

[image: Above code showing graph as below image.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need every date specified on the axis, you need to use the `hAxis.ticks` option.  `ticks` takes an array of values to label on the axis, and can either be a value:

```
hAxis: {
    ticks: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

or an object specifying the value and label to use:

```
hAxis: {
    ticks: [{v: 1, f: '1'}, {v: 2, f: 'apple'}, {v: 3, f: '$3'}, {v: 4, f: 'New York'}]
}
```

In your case, since you want to display all dates from your data, you will probably want to build the `ticks` array based on the DataTable contents:

```
hAxis: {
    ticks: dataTable.getDistinctValues(0)
}
```

Comment: ticks: dataTable.getDistinctValues(0); does not working in following code